# Writing load word without using load word instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mips64

I want to write

```
.text
main:
    lw  $t2, c

.data 
c: .word 1
```

without using lw, on mars
I tried

```
 add    $t2,$t2,c
```

and also

```
addi    $t2,$t2,0($c)
```

but they dont work
How do I do this

Comment: You can't do that. If you need to avoid `lw` specifically, you can reproduce its behavior using `lb`.

Comment: MIPS is a [load/store architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load%E2%80%93store_architecture), which means only loads and stores can access memory. You can't do that with add or any other instructions

Comment: @Jester: or two `lhu` instead of 4 `lbu`  (and you would want lbu to zero-extend, not sign-extend with `lb`).  Or LWL / LWR unaligned-load instructions. 
 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180409-00/?p=98465).  For addresses that actually are aligned, you only need one of those two.